# Jenkins initialissation and login not working as expected

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I had a jenkins installation in tomcat and moved it to another place. This was not working so i just deleted jenkins and tomcat and made them new. After making the setenv.sh in tomcat to give "JAVA_HOME" and "JENKINS_HOME" the tmocat starts the "JENKINS_HOME"- folder is created and the files are generated. After calling the site i dont get the expected "Unlock Jenkins Site" but a Login-Site. There is an "initialAdminPassword" file and also trying to login with admin and the initial-pw does not work. Also trying to disable security has no effect. Also deleting the config.xml has no effect. It's not created again but jenkins is running with the login-site. I really don't know what is going on there

Answer (score 1):

In my case jenkins was accessing a hidden folder "userHome/.jenkins" in the old directory and not the new created in the new "JENKINS_HOME". After deleting the hidden .jenkins directory the initial(unlock) page came up and a new .jenkins was created in userHome(not JENKINS_HOME) where the initial password was generated.